# javascript enter number of seconds - not less than zero

Tags: javascript, input, time

i am facing an issue in javascript. i want to do user enter number of seconds in input field.
but the condition is that `users can't enter number of seconds less than zero.`

how can a make the code logic?

```js
function sec(){  
//your code logic is here
console.log("number of seconds is not less than");
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="seconds">Number of seconds:</label>
  <input type="number" id="seconds" name="seconds">
  <button onclick="sec()">Click</button>
</form>
```

what should i do? anyone help me?

Comment: What is the issue here? Why are you not able to simply check if the value is < 0 or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your expectation about the input value as attributes on your input:

Specifically `required min="0"` would meet your needs.

```js
function sec(){  
//your code logic is here
console.log("number of seconds is not less than");
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="seconds">Number of seconds:</label>
  <input type="number" id="seconds" name="seconds" required min="0">
  <button onclick="sec()">Click</button>
</form>
```

Comment: This will block a negative number from being entered using the arrow buttons/spinner. However, the user can still manually enter a negative number and have that field's value read as a negative number, thus bypassing the min attribute.

Comment: @palaѕн they can enter a negative value but it's not going to be valid. Just like every other sane validation works, really. I **hate** when overzealous sanitisation wipes the input when it's invalid - it's better to correct your mistake than re-fill the entire input.

Answer (score 0):

With JavaScript you can convert your user's input to a Number then check its value with an equality condition.

E.g. you could fill out your sec() function like this:

```js
function sec() {
  const seconds_str = document.getElementById("seconds").value;
  const seconds_num = parseInt(seconds_str, 10); // note: you could use parseFloat for decimal fractions
  let result = "";
  
  if (seconds_num < 0) {
    result = "Is less than zero :'(";
  } else {
    result = "Is NOT less than zero :)";
  }
  
  console.log("User input = " + seconds_str);
  console.log("Converted to integer = " + seconds_num);
  console.log(result);
  
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="seconds">Number of seconds:</label>
  <input type="number" id="seconds" name="seconds">
  <button onclick="sec()" type="button">Click</button>
</form>
```

It would be up to you what you do when you detect a number less than zero. E.g. prevent form submitting, show an error message etc...

Comment: thanks your response [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1596148/karl-bishop)